# Can EJS work with existing html pages and use tokens?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've been using EJS in my node js app and it is working well but I also have an HTML page built prior to using EJS.

I like the ability to pass and object to the EJS page and make it part of the page. AN example:

```
 response.render("index", { name: "bob" );
```

But that uses the render command that IIRC has some issues with full on HTML pages (paths and so on) so I use:

```
 response.redirect("mypage.html");
```

Is it possible to pass variables to an HTML page like the EJS page?

EJS page using variables inline:

```
<div>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <h3><%= locals?.name %></h3>
</div>
```

**Update:**
I sort of got it to work. If a better way is available please mention it. See answer

Comment: i think you cant with .html

Comment: @cmgchess I sort of got it to work by making some concessions (moved the page to another directory and changed the file extension).

Answer (score 0):

I sort of got it to work. It seems to work anyway.

```
app.set("view-engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static('public'));

// before 
response.redirect("/mypage.html");
// after
response.redirect("mypage.ejs", { name: "john" });
```

The first thing I tried was to render the HTML file where it was in the public directory and it said it couldn't find `mypage.html` in the `views` directory.

```
response.render("/mypage.html"); // error
```

So I copied `mypage.html` into the views directory and tried again and it said it didn't have a module for `HTML` files.

```
response.render("/mypage.html"); // error
```

So I renamed the file extension from `/mypage.html` to `/mypage.ejs` and it still couldn't find the page.

```
response.render("/mypage.ejs"); // error
```

So I removed the preceding slash `mypage.ejs` and it found it and it loaded in the css and js.

```
response.render("mypage.html"); // no error
```

So far it seems to be working correctly.

The path issues existed but if I put the HTML page in the views directory, use render instead of redirect and kept all external assets in the public directory where they were it appears to work.

I can now pass in variables to the `html` page.